# Why is my app trying to load bourbon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bourbon

I'm having a weird gem problem here.
Since the last time I ran bundle install, my app crashes spectacularily with this nice error message: 
Sass::SyntaxError
File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon.

I don't get it, since I'm NOT using bourbon! It's not in the gemfile, and not in the generated gemfile.lock
I can't find why my app tries to load it now, but it does so at the first image it finds in the views.

I've tried to run `gem pristine --all`, with no success.

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake', '11.3.0'

#LogLinkedIn 
#gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2'
#TimeDiff
gem 'time_difference'
#LogFacebook
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
#LogTwitter
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
#LogGoogle
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem 'omniauth'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.9"
gem 'chosen-rails'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "jquery-ui-rails"

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'devise', '3.4.1'
#bootstrap-sass is not relevant to the tutorial, but I like it for styling.
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'

gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# droits d'accès
gem "cancan"
gem 'minitest'
# gem 'paper_trail'
# traductions
gem 'globalize', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'rails-i18n'
# for avatars
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
# for datum validations
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 4.0'
# crop image
gem 'jcrop-rails-v2'
# datepicker calendar
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
#interface admin
gem "administrate", "~> 0.1.4"

# autocomplete search
gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'
# seed dump
gem 'seed_dump'

#gems for async actions
gem 'private_pub'
gem 'thin'

gem 'sunspot_solr'
gem 'sunspot_rails'

# pagination
gem 'kaminari'
#text editor
gem 'ckeditor_rails'
# wizardify models
gem 'wicked'
gem 'unread'
# mangopay!
gem 'mangopay'
gem 'countries'
gem 'progress_bar'
# conversations & messages
gem 'mailboxer'
# cron jobs
gem 'whenever', :require => false

# validate card number
gem 'jquery-form-validator-rails'


# datetimepicker
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.10.6'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.37'

gem 'fullcalendar-rails'

#Sans la Gem Erreur concernant les Images_Tags
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

gem 'bigbluebutton_rails', github: 'mconf/bigbluebutton_rails'



gem 'resque', :require => "resque/server"

gem 'devise_lastseenable'

gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"

gem 'capybara' #Pour les test

gem "rails-erd"

gem 'active_interaction'
gem 'hashie'
gem 'pluck_to_hash'
gem 'drafting'
gem 'ruby-duration'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  #gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'sunspot-rails-tester'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

And gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton_rails.git
  revision: 46ef87d87ec2f3dd14fa843f3dcbbc63ebdafe5b
  specs:
    bigbluebutton_rails (2.1.0)
      bigbluebutton-api-ruby (~> 1.6)
      browser (~> 0.8.0)
      rails (>= 4.0.0)
      resque (~> 1.25.1)
      resque-scheduler (~> 3.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    active_interaction (3.4.0)
      activemodel (>= 4, < 6)
    activejob (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.5.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    administrate (0.1.5)
      autoprefixer-rails (~> 6.0)
      datetime_picker_rails (~> 0.0.7)
      jquery-rails (~> 4.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.16)
      momentjs-rails (~> 2.8)
      neat (~> 1.1)
      normalize-rails (~> 3.0)
      rails (~> 4.2)
      sass-rails (~> 5.0)
      selectize-rails (~> 0.6)
    arel (6.0.3)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.5.1.1)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bigbluebutton-api-ruby (1.6.0)
      xml-simple (~> 1.1)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.6.4.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (4.17.42)
      momentjs-rails (>= 2.8.1)
    browser (0.8.0)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (3.4.0)
      columnize (~> 0.8)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
      slop (~> 3.6)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    capybara (2.10.1)
      addressable
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    capybara-screenshot (1.0.14)
      capybara (>= 1.0, < 3)
      launchy
    carrierwave (0.11.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      mimemagic (>= 0.3.0)
    choice (0.2.0)
    chosen-rails (1.5.2)
      coffee-rails (>= 3.2)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      sass-rails (>= 3.2)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    ckeditor_rails (4.5.10)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    cookiejar (0.3.3)
    countries (1.2.5)
      currencies (~> 0.4.2)
      i18n_data (~> 0.7.0)
    crack (0.4.3)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    currencies (0.4.2)
    daemons (1.2.4)
    datetime_picker_rails (0.0.7)
      momentjs-rails (>= 2.8.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    devise (3.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise_lastseenable (0.0.6)
      devise
      rails (>= 3.0.4)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    drafting (0.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.1)
    em-http-request (1.1.5)
      addressable (>= 2.3.4)
      cookiejar (!= 0.3.1)
      em-socksify (>= 0.3)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.3)
      http_parser.rb (>= 0.6.0)
    em-socksify (0.3.1)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0.beta.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.0.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_girl (4.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.7.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.7.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faye (1.2.3)
      cookiejar (>= 0.3.0)
      em-http-request (>= 0.3.0)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
      faye-websocket (>= 0.9.1)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.5.1)
    faye-websocket (0.10.4)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.5.1)
    ffaker (2.2.0)
    font-awesome-sass (4.7.0)
      sass (>= 3.2)
    fullcalendar-rails (3.0.0.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 4.0.5, < 5.0.0)
      jquery-ui-rails (>= 5.0.2)
      momentjs-rails (>= 2.9.0)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    globalize (5.0.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0, < 4.3)
      activerecord (>= 4.2.0, < 4.3)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    haml-rails (0.9.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 5.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.1)
    hashdiff (0.3.0)
    hashie (3.4.6)
    highline (1.7.8)
    html2haml (2.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (~> 4.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    i18n_data (0.7.0)
    iso8601 (0.9.1)
    jbuilder (2.6.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jcrop-rails-v2 (0.9.12.3)
    jquery-form-validator-rails (0.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    jquery-rails (4.2.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-turbolinks (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      turbolinks
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.6)
    kaminari (0.17.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    mailboxer (0.14.0)
      carrierwave (>= 0.5.8)
      rails (>= 4.2.0)
    mangopay (3.0.25)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.7)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.1)
    momentjs-rails (2.10.6)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    mono_logger (1.1.0)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    neat (1.8.0)
      sass (>= 3.3)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    nokogiri (1.6.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    normalize-rails (3.0.3)
    oauth (0.5.1)
    oauth2 (1.2.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.3.1)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    omniauth-facebook (4.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.4.1)
      jwt (~> 1.5.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth (>= 1.1.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (>= 1.3.1)
    omniauth-oauth (1.1.0)
      oauth
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-twitter (1.2.1)
      json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.1)
    options (2.3.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.3.7)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
    pg (0.17.1)
    pluck_to_hash (1.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.2)
    pr_geohash (1.0.0)
    private_pub (1.0.3)
      faye
    progress_bar (1.0.5)
      highline (~> 1.6)
      options (~> 2.3.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.5.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.5.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.5.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.5.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.5.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-erd (1.5.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      choice (~> 0.2.0)
      ruby-graphviz (~> 1.2)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails-i18n (4.0.9)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      railties (~> 4.0)
    rails-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.3)
      rails (>= 3.2)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (4.2.5.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.5.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.5.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.3.0)
    rdoc (4.2.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.3.1)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    responders (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    resque (1.25.2)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      redis-namespace (~> 1.3)
      sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
      vegas (~> 0.1.2)
    resque-scheduler (3.1.0)
      mono_logger (~> 1.0)
      redis (~> 3.0)
      resque (~> 1.25)
      rufus-scheduler (~> 2.0)
    rsolr (1.1.2)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    rspec-core (3.5.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-rails (3.5.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-support (3.5.0)
    ruby-duration (3.2.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      i18n
      iso8601
    ruby-graphviz (1.2.2)
    ruby_parser (3.8.3)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.1)
    rufus-scheduler (2.0.24)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.22)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    seed_dump (3.2.4)
      activerecord (>= 4)
      activesupport (>= 4)
    selectize-rails (0.12.3)
    sexp_processor (4.7.0)
    sinatra (1.4.7)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slop (3.6.0)
    spring (2.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    sprockets (3.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    sunspot (2.2.7)
      pr_geohash (~> 1.0)
      rsolr (>= 1.1.1, < 3)
    sunspot-rails-tester (1.0.0)
      sunspot_rails (>= 1.2)
      sunspot_solr (>= 1.2)
    sunspot_rails (2.2.7)
      nokogiri
      rails (>= 3)
      sunspot (= 2.2.7)
    sunspot_solr (2.2.7)
    thin (1.7.0)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (>= 1, < 3)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    time_difference (0.5.0)
      activesupport
    timeliness (0.3.8)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unread (0.8.2)
      activerecord (>= 3)
    validates_timeliness (4.0.2)
      timeliness (~> 0.3.7)
    vcr (3.0.3)
    vegas (0.1.11)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    webmock (2.1.0)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
      hashdiff
    websocket-driver (0.6.4)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
    whenever (0.9.7)
      chronic (>= 0.6.3)
    wicked (1.3.1)
      railties (>= 3.0.7)
    xml-simple (1.1.5)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_interaction
  administrate (~> 0.1.4)
  bigbluebutton_rails!
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  bootstrap-sass
  bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (~> 4.17.37)
  byebug (= 3.4.0)
  cancan
  capybara
  capybara-screenshot
  chosen-rails
  ckeditor_rails
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  coffee-script-source (= 1.8.0)
  countries
  devise (= 3.4.1)
  devise_lastseenable
  drafting
  factory_girl_rails (~> 4.0)
  ffaker
  font-awesome-sass
  fullcalendar-rails
  globalize (~> 5.0.0)
  haml-rails (~> 0.9)
  hashie
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jcrop-rails-v2
  jquery-form-validator-rails
  jquery-rails
  jquery-turbolinks
  jquery-ui-rails
  kaminari
  mailboxer
  mangopay
  minitest
  momentjs-rails (~> 2.10.6)
  omniauth
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-google-oauth2
  omniauth-twitter
  paperclip (~> 4.3)
  pg (= 0.17.1)
  pluck_to_hash
  private_pub
  progress_bar
  rails (= 4.2.5.1)
  rails-erd
  rails-i18n
  rails-jquery-autocomplete
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.2)
  rake (= 11.3.0)
  resque
  rspec-rails (~> 3.0)
  ruby-duration
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  seed_dump
  spring
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.11)
  sunspot-rails-tester
  sunspot_rails
  sunspot_solr
  thin
  time_difference
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unread
  validates_timeliness (~> 4.0)
  vcr
  web-console (~> 2.0)
  webmock
  whenever
  wicked

BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.6
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Administrate requires bourbon.  Pretty sure there was a pull request to resolve that, so I would update administrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bourbon is a dependency in [Administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate). Looks like there is a recent, open issue around this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate/pull/673.

Comment: Ok, thx for the info. I've read the thread but I still don't understand how to fix my problem... :-(

Comment: This is an issue that Administrate needs to resolve, not you. So unfortunately, it may not work until they fix the issue and cut a release.

Comment: I have been waiting for this fix for awhile also.. i have backed out administrate for the time being.. it sucks.. but not much you can do about it..

Comment: Heads up: Administrate 0.4.0 was recently released which should resolve the Bourbon issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is trying to load Bourbon gem because it is a dependency of the Administrate gem.

If you are also trying to use or plan to upgrade to Rails 5 someday, you want to upgrade your gemfile like so:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.7'
gem 'administrate', github: 'greetpoint/administrate', branch: 'rails5'
gem 'bourbon', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.4'
```

Keep in mind you may run into other dependency issues that will require resolving.